# How to prove an asymptotical converge estimations to the MLE estimations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, copula

To estimate the parameters of copulas, both the classical maximum likelihood method (MLE) and alternative methods can be used, for example, [the natural sampler and the efficient importance sampler](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jae.1197).

Let us assume that the parameter(s) of a copula change dynamically and are described by a latent stochastic process. The parameters of such a process are estimated using MLE, and then modeling (1,000 iterations) is carried out using a method different from MLE (for instance, by a natural sampler). As the result we have found average parameter's values and confidence intervals for them are calculated.

**Question.**
Is it possible to conclude that the obtained estimations converge asymptotically to  the MLE estimations?